# Firebase when add/delete data, app do functions more than once

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have problems with my money app. When I add/delete data from my app (products collection), my app do function "sumPrices()" more than one. For example: When I add one product, make once, add another product, make twice, add another product make three etc. This happen in the same way with delete data.

A do something wrong in my code?

Callback.push push data do array where I unsubscribe events from firebase.
AddStatsUI add UI to my DOM.

index.js:

```
// delete products
    const handleTableClick = e => {
      console.log(e); // mouseevent
      if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
          const id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
          db.collection('users')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .collection('products')
              .doc(id)
              .delete()
              .then(() => {
                  // show message
                  updateMssg.innerText = `Product was deleted`;
                  updateMssg.classList.add('act');
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      updateMssg.innerText = '';
                      updateMssg.classList.remove('act');

                  }, 3000);
                  productUI.delete(id);
                  products.sumPrices(user.uid, callbacks).then(value => {
                      sumStats.addStatsUI('','');
                      const unsubscribe = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(snapshot => {

                        sumStats.addStatsUI(value[0], snapshot.data().budget);
                      })
                      callbacks.push(unsubscribe);
                  });


          })
      }
    }
    table.addEventListener('click', handleTableClick);
    callbacks.push(() => table.removeEventListener('click', handleTableClick))


    //add new products to firebase
    const handleExpenseFormSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const name = expenseForm.productName.value.trim();
      const price = Number(expenseForm.price.value.trim());

      console.log(`Product added: ${name}, ${price}`);
      const user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      products.addProduct(name, price, user)
          .then(() => {
              products.sumPrices(user, callbacks).then(value => {
                  sumStats.addStatsUI('','');
                  const unsubscribe = db.collection('users').doc(user).onSnapshot(snapshot => {

                      sumStats.addStatsUI(value, snapshot.data().budget);
                  })
                  callbacks.push(unsubscribe);
              });
              expenseForm.reset()
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

    }
    expenseForm.addEventListener('submit', handleExpenseFormSubmit);
    callbacks.push(() => expenseForm.removeEventListener('submit', handleExpenseFormSubmit))
```

product.js:

```
class Product {
constructor(name, price, budget, user) {
    this.products = db.collection('users');
    this.budget = budget;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.user = user;
} 
async addProduct(name, price, user) { //dodaje produkt do firebase
    const now = new Date();
    const product = {
        name: name,
        price: price,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now),
    };
    const response = await this.products.doc(user).collection('products').add(product);
    return response;
}
getProducts(callback, user){ //download list from firebase
    this.products.doc(user).collection('products')
        .orderBy("created_at", "desc")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                if(change.type === 'added'){
                    //udpate UI

                    return callback(change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
                } 
            });


    });
}
updateBudget(budget, user){

    this.budget = budget;
    db.collection('users').doc(user).update({budget: budget});
    // callbacks.push(unsubscribe);
}
async sumPrices(user, callbacks){

    let finish = [];
    const unsubscribe = this.products.doc(user).collection('products').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let totalCount = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        totalCount += doc.data().price;
        });

        const a = totalCount;
        console.log(a);
        finish.push(a);
        return finish;
    })
    callbacks.push(unsubscribe);
    return finish;
};
```

};

sumStatsUI.js:

```
class Stats {
constructor(stats, circle, budget){
    this.stats = stats;
    this.circle = circle;
    this.budget = budget;
}
addStatsUI(data, budget){
    if(data) {
    const outcome = Math.round(data * 100) / 100;
    const sumAll = Math.round((budget - outcome) * 100) / 100;

    this.stats.innerHTML += `
    <div><span class="budget-name">Budget: </span>  <span class="stat-value">${budget}$</span></div>
    <div><span class="budget-name">Outcome: </span> <span class="stat-value outcome-value">${outcome}$</span></div>
    <div><span class="budget-name">All: </span> <span class="stat-value last-value">${sumAll}$</span></div>
    `;
    const circle = Math.round(((outcome * 100) / budget) * 100) / 100;
    this.circle.innerHTML += `${circle}%`;

    } else {
    this.stats.innerHTML = '';
    this.circle.innerHTML = '';
}};
```

};

export default Stats;

[I add console.log to sumPrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0NEV.png)

[App screenshot, when I add 2 products and try update budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG0S7.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome! I am not able to understand what is exact problem. From code it seems that each time when you add the product sumPrices is being called. On the other hand this seems to be a problem too... How it should work than...?

Comment: Everytime when I add or delete data from table with expense (look screenshot) this make sumPrices() but app do code sumPrices() like this: When I add one product, make once, add another product, make twice, add another product make three etc. This happen in the same way with delete data. When this happen this return sumPrices() ascending. first time: return result once, next return twice etc. If this isn't enough, I can make video, how it's work.

Comment: You have a subscription that you didn't unsubscribe, for example each time you call `getProducts` it will create a new subscription

Comment: Where I must put unsubscribe to fix it? To getProducts in function or index.js somewhere? @Reza

Comment: @mGryska two ways: you can call getProducts once and that function needs to return observable, you subscribe to it, then when your component is destroying you need to unsubscribe, the other option use `first()` in your pipe it will end the subscription, and each time you can call getProducts

Comment: @mGryska - I have an impression that you are adding listeners and removing them after one call. Isnt it better to use `get()`? What are `product`and `callbacks` objects in frist part of code?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, a add some improvement to my code, but still have problems with subscriptions. Now everything it's okey, but when I log out and log in functions getProducts() and updateBudget() no unsubscribe.

Code here:
index.js:

```
//get the products and render
const unsubscribe = products.getProducts((data, id) => {

  console.log(data, id);
  productUI.render(data, id);

}, user.uid);
callbacks.push(unsubscribe);

    //update budget + form
const handleBudgetFormSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //update budget
  const budget = Number(budgetForm.budget_value.value.trim());
  sumStats.addStatsUI('', '');
  products.updateBudget(budget, user.uid);
  //reset form
  budgetForm.reset();

  const budgetCart = document.querySelector('#budget');
  budgetCart.classList.remove('active');

  // show message
  updateMssg.innerText = `Your budget was updated to ${budget}$`;
  updateMssg.classList.add('act');

  setTimeout(() => {
    updateMssg.innerText = '';
    updateMssg.classList.remove('act');
  }, 3000);
};
budgetForm.addEventListener('submit', handleBudgetFormSubmit);
callbacks.push(() =>
  budgetForm.removeEventListener('submit', handleBudgetFormSubmit)
);
```

and else to onAuthStateChanged() -> if(user):

```
  } else {
console.log('user logged out');
authUI('');
productUI.render('');
sumStats.addStatsUI('');
console.log('Callbacks array', callbacks);
callbacks.forEach(callback => callback());
callbacks.length = 0;
```

}
});

getProducts() and updateBudget():

```
  getProducts(callback, user) {
//download list from firebase
this.products
  .doc(user)
  .collection('products')
  .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {

      if (change.type === 'added') {
        //udpate UI
        return callback(change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
      }
    });
  });
```

}

```
  updateBudget(budget, user) {
    console.log('budget', budget, user);
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    // this.budget = budget;
    db.collection('users')
      .doc(user)
      .update({ budget: budget });
  }
```

When I log out and log in:

When I have getProducts and add product to collection, this function render (render()) product twice, but add to collection once. When I update budget this return budget but after that, return 0 (on DOM where show budget a can see "Infinity")

And one thing, when I log out, console return error:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at eval (index.js:182)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval [as next] (index.js:182)
    at eval (index.cjs.js:1226)
    at eval (index.cjs.js:1336)
```

I think it's because getProducts and updateBudget don't return unsubscribe, but undefined.

Maybe someone have solution for this?